# JQuery Plot, exists an OnCompleteDraw Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

i want to know if is possible get an event before the JQueryPlot draw a graph and after that. If somebody have an example better.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hooks plugin in order to bind some events.

You can find the [jqPlot documentation here](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#$.jqplot) and a working example [on jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/a9a7ecqo/1/) (once you have clicked the url, close the two alert prompts and click on the "Run" button in order  to see correctly how it works :

```
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
$.jqplot.preDrawHooks.push(function(){
  alert('predraw');
});
$.jqplot.postDrawHooks.push(function(){
  alert('postDraw');
});
```